# Update MySQL tables with some duplicated entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

#### Table 1

```
Column 1 |  Column 2 |  Column 3
---------------------------------
1        |  a        |  10
         |           |
3        |  g        |  30
         |           |
5        |  f        |  50
         |           |
7        |  f        |  70
```

#### Table 2

```
Column 1 |  Column 2 |  Column 3
---------------------------------
10       |  bb       |  30

50       |  cc       |  40
```

Now, I need to copy the rows from `table 2` to `table 1`.

The problem is:

If any entry in `column 3` already exists in `table 1`. `Column 3`, then `column 1` and `column 2` from `table 1` are updated with data from `table 2`. Rows that don't exist are just added in the end of the table.

Comment: why are they being updated... are you doing an upsert?

Comment: simply puting, I have 2 tables with products. and I need the products from table 2 in table 1. but there are some products duplicated

Comment: which column(s) defines a prod id? And if there exists the same key in both tables what do you want to do with the value in col 3... sum, avg?

Comment: in this example it would be the column3. col3 would never be changed, col 2 and 1 are the ones thas should de updated in case of duplicated entries.

the problem is resolved now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update `Column1` and `Column2` if a record exists for `Column3` else add new record, use:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Table1Column3 on Table1(Column3);

INSERT INTO Table1(Column1, Column2, Column3)
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM Table2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Column1 = Table2.Column1, Column2 = Table2.Column2
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a unique index in table 1 on `column1` and `column2`:

```
create unique index table1_column1_column2 on table1(column1, column2);
```

Then use `insert on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into table1(column1, column2, column3)
    select column1, column2, column3
    from table2
    on duplicate key update column3 = table2.column3;
```

Comment: this didn´t work, I used the example that Linger gave me, but thanks